# Algorithm for data fit with conditionals

Tags: algorithm, data-fitting

**Background**

I need a (sort of a) bandwidth estimation algorithm.

There are two peers, the sender and the receiver. Sender transmits some data at (nearly) constant bitrate, each data packet contains its local time (`Ts`).
Receiver once in a while (i.e. not necessarily after every received packet) send a feedback, which contains both the sender and the receiver time stamps (`Ts`, `Tr`).

The sender's goal is, based on those feedbacks, detection of the actual network bandwidth and possible congestion. Based on this the sender should adjust the transmitted bandwidth.

Assumptions:

- Packet loss and reorders are negligible.
- Bandwidth is a slowly-varying function. Perhaps even approximated at constant within a reasonably small time window.
- The congestion (i.e. delay) is the result of over-estimating of the bandwidth. Simply speaking, when too much data is sent the network bandwidth is saturated, and the extra data is accumulated in one of the network nodes.

Now, based on those assumptions we have the following model. Define:

- `i` - is the feedback index.
- `dTs[i] := Ts[i+1] - Ts[i]`
- `dTr[i] := Tr[i+1] - Tr[i]`
- `Q[i]` - is the send queue size (in bytes). In case of the congestion it's non-zero.
- `X[i]` - is the size of the data transmitted by sender within [`i`, `i+1`] interval.
- `B[i]` - is the actual **network** bandwidth (slowly-varying, almost constant). I.e. the maximum bandwidth that can be transmitted, without congestion accumulation.

**Problem**

Then we can yield the following recursive formulas for `i` => `i+1` transition.

- network saturation criteria:

  - `Q[i] + X[i] >= B[i] * dTs[i]`
- If saturation reached:

  - `dTr[i] = X[i] / B[i]`
  - `Q[i+1] = Q[i] + X[i] - B[i] * dTs[i]`
- Otherwise:

  - `dTr[i] = dTs[i] - Q[i] / B[i]`
  - `Q[i+1] = 0`

`B[i]` and `Q[i]` are unknown, `dTs[i]`, `dTr[i]` and `X[i]` are known.

Now, I need an algorithm to fit the unknowns to satisfy the recursive formulas. By fitting I mean minimizing the residuals in the recusrsive formulas, i.e. predicted `dTr[i]` vs actual.

The problem is that our recursive formulas contain conditionals (`if`), hence the fitting can not be done by only analytical methods. Moreover, in some situations the requested parameters can't be deduced: if the bandwidth is never saturated then we don't know the `B[i]`, we can only guess its lower bound. And if there's always a congestion, then we don't know absolute value of `Q[i]`, we can only predict its change.

But apart from those ambiguities (which are both abnormal for the sender, and should be treated separately) the problem seems to be well-defined and solvable. I'm trying to find an effective solution.

One method I can think of is trying substituting init-guess conditionals, once they are known the problem turns into analytical and has well-defined solution. Next, we can either try all variants of conditionals or iteratively each time change one of them, until we reach optimal residual.

Or alternatively we can start from init-guess of `B[i]` and `Q[i]`, at each iteration compute the residual and its derivative w.r.t. both parameters, and then iteratively adjust them.

I wonder if data fit with conditionals is a well-known problem with suitable solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not an answer- just a sketch- but if the discontinuous conditional poses a difficulty, consider generalizing it to something smoother.  For example, let's represent the "network saturation criterion" as an indicator variable S = (Q[i] + X[i] - B[i] * dTs[i] > 0 ? 1 : 0).  Then dTr[i] = S*(X[i] / B[i]) + (1-S)*(dTs[i] - Q[i] / B[i]) . Suggestively, this looks like interpolation between the two alternative expressions for dTr.  Replace S with a differentiable expression that approximates the indicator e.g. a logistic function; now dTr is differentiable.

Comment: @JerryFederspiel - nice idea, thanks. I'll work this through.